# how can i check if a specific column has similar values for any row, . An example of similar i this case is 456 is similar to 654

Tags: pandas, filter, selection, similarity

**I began with a sample data frame and tried to check if the sum of any values in that column is the same for all set of rows**

```
#### load data###
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(iris.data,columns=iris.feature_names)
df.head()
```

this gives me an error "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()." and also does not account for all the rows

```
m=df.shape[0]
columns = [0]


df.iloc[2, :] = [3, 4, 5, 1]
df.iloc[3, :] = [3, 4, 4, 1]

for row1 in range(m-1):
    for row2 in range(row1+1, m):
        if (df.iloc[row1,columns].sum == df.iloc[row2, columns].sum).all():`
            # logic
            print ('Good!')
        else:
            print(f"nothing")
```

**unfortunately the sum function here doesnt check per row and i am unsure of how to do this**

Answer (score 0):

`Map` a function that adds the digits then use `np.where` to assign `'Good!'` where the values are `duplicated`.

In:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'data': [456,654,235,532,111,354]})

def sum_digits(n):
   r = 0
   while n:
       r, n = r + n % 10, n // 10
   return r

df['status'] = np.where(df.data.map(sum_digits).duplicated(keep=False), 'Good!', 'nothing')
```

Out:

```
   data   status
0   456    Good!
1   654    Good!
2   235    Good!
3   532    Good!
4   111  nothing
5   354  nothing
```